# Grunt Uglify breaks ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, gruntjs, minify, uglifyjs

I have a function:

```
    function createAddressList(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            async: true
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
    }
```

which translates minified to:

```
function g(b){a.ajax(http://localhost/testpage/b,cache:!1,async:!0).done(function(a){alert("Data Saved: "+a)})}
```

---

this results in an error,

chrome :

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
...ion g(b){a.ajax(http://localhost/testpage/b,cache:!1,async:!0).done(f
```

How can I solve this? Help is much appreciated

Comment: My suggestion would be to run the JS without uglifying it and see if you come across any errors in the console.

Comment: Well the minified code is totally broken. Report it as a bug. Even if your code is wrong, Uglify should at least report an error and not produce worse code.

Comment: Without minification, everything works

Answer (score -2):

Use mangle option to make exceptions when renaming $ to jQuery:

1) Use jQuery instead $

```
function createAddressList(url) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            async: true
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
    }
```

2) Config Uglify

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    options: {
      mangle: {
        except: ['jQuery']
      }
    },
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```